# Chartjs x axis scaling

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Is there a way to pass a dataset to x-axis with [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/)? Documentation says:

`The line chart requires an array of labels for each of the data points. This is show on the X axis.`

What I mean is not labels, integers. i.e. (1,y) (11,y) should be away from each other 10 units.

Comment: Any news on this one? I am looking for a chart library which can scale on the X axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Chart.Scatter plugin. It allows to specify X-axis scale